# Can I use an Adafruit Trinket as a simple Android peripheral?

Tags: usb, usb-peripherals

I want to control the standby state of an LCD panel through an android media PC. I'm thinking of using a Trinket as a cheap android USB peripheral. Is this possible?

I'm new to Android and Adafruit but really keen to learn. Previously, I controlled my LCD panel through my Raspberry Pi GPIO interface, but I want to move to some hardware with a little more oomph!

The LCD Panel accepts a 3.3v signal to switch the screen on. Is the Trinket the right piece of hardware for this application?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Best Regards, Jabah

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what kind of interface you're hoping to use between the Android device and the Trinket, and whether the Android device has drivers for that USB class. For example, if you made the Trinket act like a mouse, and your Android device has USB HID (human interface device) support, then that would work fine - but a mouse isn't much use for controlling your LCD panel.

You need to look in the specs of the particular Android device you're using, or try it out with some existing USB devices, to find what USB classes it supports: in particular, you'll likely be wanting to use a USB-serial interface.

You'll probably also need to write some special-purpose software for your Android device, to communicate with the Trinket. I'm afraid as this isn't a programming site, we can't help you with that.